# Unable to print all the tokenized string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code which tokenize the string 2 times.
In 1st pass it tokenize based on "&" and on second pass it should tokenize based on "|".
But after 1st pass, it does not continue.
Below is sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
            
using namespace std;
            
int main () {
             
    char value[] = "Hello | my | Name & is | Pratik & lets see";
    char *token = strtok (value, "&");
 
    while (token != NULL) {
        cout << "\n token: " << token;

        char *token_1 = strtok (token, "|");
        while (token_1 != NULL) {
                  
            cout << "\n token_1: " << token_1;
            token_1 = strtok (NULL, "|");
        }
        token = strtok (NULL, "&");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting out put
token: Hello | my | Name
token_1: Hello
token_1:  my
token_1:  Name

I'm I missing anything?

Comment: First thing to do: [edit] and format and indent your code properly.

Comment: Also tell us what output you expect and what output you get. Don't answer with a comment but [edit] the question.

Comment: `strtok` cannot be used in this fashion.  It uses a static char buffer internally.  Thus you cannot jump back and forth using `strtok` on the same string using a different delimiter.  You're using C++ -- there is no need to use `strtok` to accomplish your goal.  There are much, much better ways in C++ to do this task.

Comment: Related: [do it in C++ not in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680/1387438).

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` has only enough brainpower to keep track of ***just one*** string being tokenized.

The shown code uses ***two*** nested `strtok` loops, with what's effectively ***two*** strings, and expects each loop's `strtok` to be independent of each other, and handle only its own string. Unfortunately `strtok` does not work this way. Calling `strtok` with a `NULL` string value results in the ***most recent*** `strtok`-ed string continuing to get tokenized.

However, the solution to your conundrum is very simple: replace `strtok` [with `strtok_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), and provide the appropriate state pointer to each instance.